# Running from command line-writing to file

Tags: java, cmd

I'm kinda new here. I'm trying to run a java program through the command line but I need to output to a file. So, in the command line I run:

`[my filepath]> javac filename.java`

And then I run

`[my filepath]> javac filename.java > outputfileIneed.txt`

In `filename.java`, I use `System.out.println()`, and the computer creates a text file in the appropriate location, but the file is blank. What do I write to fix this? This seems to be more of a java problem; is there a command other than `System.out.println()` to print to a text file from commmand line?

Please ask for more information if you need.

Comment: First use javac filename.java to compile java file, then run java filename.java > outputfileIneed.txt

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your java file first.

```
javac filename.java
```

Then, you need to run your class file using

```
java filename > outputfileIneed.txt
```

Also, `System.out.println()` **is for console output, not for writing to file.** .

If you java program compiles and executes successfully and prints output to the console. Then, above line will do your job.

**==Updated==**

If you are using `PrintWriter` in your java code. Then, you can use below sample code.

```
public class Testing {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File ("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/directory/outputfileineed.txt");
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter ("outputfileineed.txt");
    printWriter.println ("hello");
    printWriter.close ();       
  }
}
```

Please note that, once you include above line of code in your java file. Then, you only need to compile your java file again and run as show below

```
java filename
```

Comment: Yeah, I do that. I said that in the comments and in the edit I made.

Comment: Please see my post then

Comment: Thank you for the prompt change. I created a file using `PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(System.out, true)`, and I still couldn't write to the file. I feel like I'm missing some big detail here.

Comment: So then where does the `outputfileineed.txt` come in?

Comment: you need to provide file name in your code. Please refer my updated code

Comment: So then what's the point in having the `>outputfileIneed.txt`? That's the feature that I need to make use of!

Comment: that's what I mentioned in first place. If you need to use `>outputfileIneed.txt` then earlier suggestion should work

Comment: With a Printwriter I can't use this function because I need a file name, but you originally suggested to print to the console; I need to print to a file. I'm extremely sorry but I don't quite understand...

Comment: Yes, earlier suggestion will print to console. And `>` will redirect it to file name. That's what I said.. **`System.out.println()` is for console output, not for writing to file**. You don't seems to be clear with your requirement

Comment: The original issue was that System.out.println () wasn't working. I'd still end up with a blank file.  Looks like we've gone full-circle :)

Comment: As I mentioned `>` will redirect console output it to file name. So, first you need to check whether your java program print anything on console on or not.  If yes, then it should write to your file

Comment: If you are still having issue, then you need to post your java code. If your problem resolved, then consider accepting answer

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
javac filename.java
```

is used to compile your java code.

If your code has no compile errors, it means your file `outputfileIneed.txt` will not contain anything.

After you have run your `javac filename.java` command, you need to run the following command.

```
java filename > outputfileIneed.txt
```

this will redirect the output of your java program to the `outputfileIneed.txt` file.

---

Hope this helps!